# Bind fill color manually to value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a factor which I created as follows:

```
myfactor<-c("A","B","C","D")
myfactor<-factor(myfactor)
```

I use that factor for multiple datasets for the `value` column:

```
factor(datasetA$value,levels=myfactor)
factor(datasetB$value,levels=myfactor)
```

Dataset A

```
            Type   count variable                 value
1:              1   235        1                  A
2:              2    31        1                  A
3:              3    28        1                  B
4:              4   113        1                  B
5:              5    40        1                  C
```

Dataset B

```
            Type   count variable                 value
1:              1   235        1                  B
2:              2    31        1                  B
3:              3    28        1                  B
4:              4   113        1                  B
5:              5    40        1                  C
```

**My Problem**

When I plot dataset A with the command

```
  ggplot(data=datasetA, aes(x=as.factor(variable),y=count,fill = value)) + 
    geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity", width = 1) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("#4ceb34","#ebd034","#eb34dc","#34ebc3","#3452eb","#eb3434"))
```

I get the following legend:

[image]

When I plot dataset B the legend looks like the following

[image]

I want to establish a binding between the levels and the colors: A should be green, B should be yellow...
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to assign the `values` to a *named* vector:

```
myfactor <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
vals <- setNames(c("#4ceb34","#ebd034","#eb34dc","#34ebc3","#3452eb","#eb3434"), myfactor)
```

Note that there is no need to coerce `myvector` to factor, what is needed is to have colors with names assign to them.
Then, in the plot, use layer

```
scale_fill_manual(values = vals)
```